# Where can I find the other Channel Divinity options for Clerics that are hinted at in the PHB?

Tags: dnd-4e, class-feature, cleric

For a Cleric, the PHB shows two Channel Divinity powers: Turn Undead and Divine Fortune.

However, it says there are other Channel Divinity powers, but I can't find out what these are.

**What are those other options and where can I find them? Are these (and the previously mentioned ones) available to a first level character?**

Answer (score 3):

### To start, turn to the Feats section.

Feats tagged as [Divinity] expand your options for a 1/encounter Channel Divinity power, such as *Ioun's Poise* or *Raven Queen's Blessing*. They aren't cleric-specific; rather, they use the Channel Divinity mechanic to offer a common benefit to all divine characters who follow a particular god. You have at least one feat to spend at level 1, so you can unlock one of these options if it appeals to you.

For Clerics specifically, *Divine Power* and *Dragon 399/400* offer some alternate starting options for your Channel Divinity.

Lastly, any feat tagged [Divinity] will expand your existing options, wherever it comes from. I can't provide a guaranteed complete list of those feats, but each campaign setting comes with a players' guide with [Divinity] feats specific to that campaign's deities, and *Divine Power* also includes more setting-agnostic [Divinity] feats related to a god's domain.